# Call method doesn't work

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I did one "start" class, the form class and a Adder class.

I want to add items to the listBox1 in Form1 FROM the adder class...

...but it doesn't do it !

There's no error or something like that and when i debug it, it seems to work, but there's no item in the listbox after clicking button 2 (i will mark it in the code)

I KNOW that I call the AddValue() function in the class Form1 (and then it works... i don't know why), but I want to do it from another class, because that is not the hole program, only the piece that make problems.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{         

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command2 = "ipconfig";
        string command = "telnet " + comboBox1.Text + " 13000";
        processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + command2);
        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    }

    public void AddValue(string value)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // here it "starts"
    {
        Adder adder_objet = new Adder();
        adder_objet.Add();
    }
}
public class Adder
{

    public void Add()
    {
        Form1 form1_objet = new Form1(); 
        form1_objet.AddValue("sfdg");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: `new` creates a *new* instance, so yes, you open a new form, add a value of `sfdg` to it, then the method finishes, `form1_objet` goes out of scope and the form is disposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not entirely sure about your design, but this will fix it:

```
public class Adder
{

    public void Add(Form1 myForm)
    {
        myForm.AddValue("sfdg");
    }

}
```

then in your click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // here it "starts"
{
    Adder adder_objet = new Adder();
    adder_objet.Add(this);
}
```

Comment: but how can I call the add function without using "this"?... it works if the button2_click is in the Form1 class, but then i can call it also directly like

Comment: listBox1.Items.Add("rfg")

Comment: my problem is that my running code is at the adder class and it have to add items to the listbox1 in form1, BUT the class is called by annother class (not in the code snippet)

Comment: i only used the button for help that i can directly call the the adder class - the button isn't really in the real code

Comment: What should the Adder do when called from the other class (not Form1)? Perhaps you need an interface IAddable?

Comment: it has to do the same as now - add a item to the listbox1 in form1. What do you mean with interface IAddable ? can you give me an example ? :)

Comment: I understand you better now.  You could implement Bauss's suggestion below about cretaing the public static instance. Then don't pass anything to adder.  The code there becomes Program.MainForm.Add("something");

Answer (score 1):

`Adder` class is not adding to the same instance of `Form1`. Try to modify it like this:

public class Adder
{

```
public void Add(Form1 form1_objet)
{
    form1_objet.AddValue("sfdg");
}
```

}

And then call it like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // here it "starts"
    {
        Adder adder_objet = new Adder();
        adder_objet.Add(this);
    }
```

Comment: I was typing same time as you.  Note that you pass Form1 into the constructor of Adder when calling from the event, but then the Adder class expects it in the Add method

Comment: @GinjaNinja Thanks! I corrected it. That's what happens when you don't use an IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `AddValue` on a new instance of `Form1`.

Instead create a static property that returns your main form that you created an instance of during `Application.Run`

Declare this in your `Program` class

```
public static Form1 MainForm { get; private set; }
```

And replace your `Application.Run` with this

```
MainForm = new Form1();
Application.Run(MainForm);
```

You might also want to make your `Program` class public.

At last in your `Adder.Add` method you have to call the `MainForm` property from your `Program` class.

```
public class Adder
{
    public void Add()
    {
            Form1 form1_objet = new Form1(); 
        form1_objet.AddValue("sfdg");
    }
}
```

Of course there is a few things that I'd like see modified here unless you really need a new instance of `Adder` every time then declare the `Add` method as static and perhaps the class as a whole, like this

```
public static class Adder
{
    public static void Add()
    {
        Form1 form1_objet = new Form1(); 
        form1_objet.AddValue("sfdg");
    }
}
```

Of course some of the above depends on how you're going to use it etc.

As of now this should be what you want to do.

**#Edit - 1**

You can also pass `Form1` as a variable to your `Adder` class if you do not want it static or pass it to the `Add` method.

> Example 1

```
public class Adder
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Adder(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        _form1.AddValue("sfdg");
    }
}
```

> Example 2

```
public class Adder
{
    public void Add(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1.AddValue("sfdg");
    }
}
```

I would say use **Example 1** if you're going to use `form1` more than one place within `Adder`, otherwise go with **Example 2**.

**#Edit - 2**

To elaborate on your actual code then what you have to replace for this to get it "working" is this.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // here it "starts"
{
    Adder adder_objet = new Adder();
    adder_objet.Add();
}
```

With

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // here it "starts"
{
    Adder adder_objet = new Adder();
    adder_objet.Add(this);
}
```

And

```
public class Adder
{

    public void Add(Form1 form1_object)
    {
        form1_objet.AddValue("sfdg");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Bauss, I think your part on creating a public static instance of the form does not help in this case - you do not use it in any further examples in your article, so it doesn't contribute to the answer in any way.

Comment: If you read what I said `Of course some of the above depends on how you're going to use it etc.` As it would be pointless to explain further unless necessary. However it helps in most cases where you want to share forms between other forms and/or classes (which forms technically are.)